# Is possible to integrate Angular Application in existing Angular JS Application?

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-hybrid

I want to run My new Angular 7 application in our existing Angular JS applicatio? does anyone has any demo example or Steps we should consider while doing ?

Comment: yes, it's possible to do so

Answer (score 0):

Instead of considering one app embedding another, consider 2 app pointing to each others. It will be much easier to handle as you'll have 2 seperates apps and you can run them in different environments.

I had to migrate an application from AngularJS to Angular 7. As this was a big subject, we decided to do this one feature at a time. Here is what we did:

1. Reproduce the layout of AngularJS app (v1) into your Angular app (v2)
2. Implements the feature into your v2
3. Changes every way to access the features into v1 to make them go to v2 (basically changing URL towards the v2)
4. In the layout of v2 points URL towards v1 features which have not been migrated yet

This can give you some hints to approach your problem.